# The difference ”npm r build“ and “npm run build”？

Tags: javascript, npm

Recently I tried to use "`npm r build`" as a simplified as "`npm run build`", but I found those two are different. I am wondering what does "`npm r build`" do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's check the docs. If you type this:

```
npm help r
npm help run
```

… the program will open the corresponding manual pages in your default browser. They're local files thus you don't even need internet connection:

> ```
> npm-uninstall
>
> Remove a package
> SYNOPSIS
>
> npm uninstall [<@scope>/]<pkg>[@<version>]... [-S|--save|-D|--save-dev|-O|--save-optional|--no-save]
>
> aliases: remove, rm, r, un, unlink
> ```

> ```
> npm-run-script
>
> Run arbitrary package scripts
> SYNOPSIS
>
> npm run-script <command> [--silent] [-- <args>...]
>
> alias: npm run
> ```

So `r` is an alias for a different command.